# XML-RPC pinging (google and others)

Tags: php, xml, seo, xml-rpc

I am trying to ping (SEO tactic called "ping" is used for new content to get robots index it faster) Google in PHP. Only thing I know is that I need to send my request to following url:
http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2

Probably I can use PHP [XML-RPC functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php). I don't know how to format my request and which method to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as you're concerned to do the XML-RPC request ([Example #1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php#example-4881)).

If you follow the [specification of a pingback](http://hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback), it would look like this:

```
$sourceURI = 'http://example.com/';
$targetURI = 'http://example.com/';
$service = 'http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2';

$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("pingback.ping", array($sourceURI, $targetURI));
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
    'content' => $request
)));
$file = file_get_contents($service, false, $context);
$response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
if ($response && xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
    trigger_error("xmlrpc: $response[faultString] ($response[faultCode])");
} else {
    print_r($response);
}
```

Which would give you the following output:

```
Array
(
    [flerror] => 
    [message] => Thanks for the ping.
)
```

Generally, if you don't know which method you call, you can also try [XML-RPC Introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485163/367456) - but not all XML-RPC servers offer that.

---

You asked in a comment:

> According to specs, `$targetURI` should be: *"The target of the link on the source site. This SHOULD be a pingback-enabled page"*. How can I make pingback enabled page, or more important, what is that actually?

A pingback enabled site is a website that announces an XML-RPC pinbback service as well. That's done with the HTMl `<link>` element in the `<head>` section. Example:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="http://hakre.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php" />
```

The `href` points to an XML-RPC endpoint that has the `pingback.ping` method available.

Or it's done by sending a specifc HTTP response header:

```
X-Pingback: http://charlie.example.com/pingback/xmlrpc
```

See [*pingback-enabled resource*](http://hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback#pingbackenabledpage).

So if you ping others, others should be able to ping you, too.

Comment: I should easily make request by following PHP documentation. I don't know method or which variables I need to send. I would really appriciate if you can post link to google's documentation, since I can't find it.

Comment: @dario111cro: I added the specs and extended the example code.

Comment: @dario111cro: You're welcome. Those specs weren't @ google, and as I've seen they removed the reference to it from their site, they had some kind of their own API in the past, see http://web.archive.org/web/20091119080527/http://www.google.co.kr/help/blogsearch/pinging_API.html

Comment: According to specs, $targetURI should be: "The target of the link on the source site. This SHOULD be a pingback-enabled page". How can I make pingback enabled page, or more important, what is that actually?

Comment: @dario111cro: I extended the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, I think we should use `weblogUpdates.ping` or `weblogUpdates.extendedPing` instead of `pingback.ping` to ping a site about new content.

`pingback.ping` is for a new link from one site to another, not for new content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `weblogUpdates.extendedPing` with google blog search, weblogs, Pingomatic and `weblogUpdates.ping` for other server. I created a ping tool but some server return an error  with http and https, i cannot give a bug [Online rpc xml ping](https://cloudreports.net/tools/xmlrpc-service-pinger)