# How to connect to Drupal 6 with xml-rpc

Tags: php, drupal, xml-rpc

I'm trying to connect my app with Drupal. It return me this error: "Something went wrong - -32602 : Server error. Wrong number of method parameters.". I think it should work.

Have anyone any clue what is wrong here?

My code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
require_once("IXR_Library.php");

// Create the client object
$client = new IXR_Client('http://localhost/drupal6/xmlrpc.php');
//$client->debug=true;
 $username = "admin"; 
 $password = "admin"; 
 $params = array(0,$username,$password,10); 


if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', $params)) {
    die('Something went wrong - '.$client->getErrorCode().' : '.$client->getErrorMessage());
}

$myresponse = $client->getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an [error message (Specification for Fault Code Interoperability, version 20010516)](http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/specs/rfc.fault_codes.php) from the XMLRPC endpoint you're communicating with.

It is a defined error code:

> ```
> -32602 ---> server error. invalid method parameters
> ```

The RPC method you requested was found by the server but you passed invalid parameters to it. Contact the support of the service you consume to get a list of all available methods. If your parameters should be available, contact the support and discuss the issue with them.

In your case, double-check what the Drupal manual tells you about the `metaWeblog.getRecentPosts` XMLRPC Method [blogapi_xmlrpc<sup>*Drupal API*</sup>](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!blogapi!blogapi.module/function/blogapi_xmlrpc/6):

```
array(
  'metaWeblog.getRecentPosts',
  'blogapi_metaweblog_get_recent_posts',
  array('array', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'int'),
  t('Returns a list of the most recent posts in the system.'),
),
```

If this insufficient documentation, look the missing pieces up from within the source-code of Drupal.

For example the first parameter needs to be a string but you use the integer number `0` here.

For more information how you can make use of XMLRPC Introspection please see a releated question / answer: [XMLRPC showing -32601 error (using PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485163/367456).

I do not know if drupal supports XMLRPC Introspection, but it looks like it does.

Comment: You mean that first parameter needs to be array right? Anything i try return the same error. Introspections returns bunch of warnings like: "Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\xmlrpc-discovery.php on line 713
blogger.editPost () Updates the information about an existing post. 3.. blogger.getPost 
Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\xmlrpc-discovery.php on line 712". Nothing useful :(

Comment: No, please see XMLRPC Instrospection. The first entry is the return type, the parameters follow. So the return type is array, not the first parameter. I already formulated that in the answer: You need string, but you have integer. - The errors you see just I think mean that no introspection is available or that the XMLRPC is not standard conform.